# What is the fight club theory?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Please can anyone explain what is the "fight club theory" in Game of Thrones? And does this theory relate to the books in any way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this shows zero research. A simple google search would answer this.

Comment: @Aegon That's a reason to downvote, ***not* a reason to close**.

Comment: The first rule of the Fight Club theory is "You do not talk about the Fight Club theory"

Comment: @Randal'Thor Are you going to allow a question to be closed because the OP asked something Googleable? I guess no one remembers the meta SE thread in which the ultimatum was: It! Doesn't! Matter! Someone has to be #1 on the search results. We shouldn't avoid asking questions because it's easily Googleable!

Comment: Unclear is just a BS close reason, obviously no one has trouble understanding what the OP meant by the fight club theory.

Comment: @Insane Depends what you mean by "allow" :-) I also think it shouldn't be closed, but I'm not going to modhammer it open when I was the one who answered it. I may write up a meta post about it, unless someone else like you does it first.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Good point I didn't notice you answered :)

Comment: Please do not vote to close this question again.  I am reopening it as a legitimate, if unpopular question. If you find the question objectionable on the basis of its fan-generated speculative nature, that is not, technically a reason to close, but perhaps to downvote. If the theory which has an answer below exists in the fandom it is fair game for both questions and answers.

Comment: Wishful thinking, that's all it is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I hadn't heard of this theory, but found it by Googling *"fight club theory" "game of thrones"*.

From TV Guide's [*Game of Thrones*: All the Crazy Arya Theories, Explained](http://www.tvguide.com/news/game-of-thrones-arya-theories-explained/):

> **The *Fight Club* Theory:** Some fans suggest that Arya and the Waif are not actually nemeses, but the same person, with the Waif being the Tyler Durden to Arya's Edward Norton. The meat of this theory is that the Waif and Arya represent her two possible paths - becoming No One and embracing her born identity - and that all the fights between Arya and the Waif are her inner struggles literalized. That would make the Waif's attack on Arya a (failed) last-ditch effort to kill her emotions and officially become No One.
>
> [...]
>
> However, given the absurdity of this theory and the fact that the Waif is equally emotional as Arya, it doesn't quite line up.

This is a reference to the 1999 film [*Fight Club*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club), and if you read Wikipedia's plot description you'll see why.

The theory may have originated on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/4luqf8/spoilers_everything_why_arya_and_the_waif_are_the/) last Tuesday (31 May 2016).

As for whether it relates to the books, you have to remember that *A Song of Ice and Fire* and *Game of Thrones* have considerably diverged at this point, and the show has moved beyond all the currently existing books. It may be that the theory will also be valid in the books; it may also be that it will be invalidated even in the show when the next episode airs.

Comment: Never watched the movie. but surely going to watch

Comment: Sort of interesting... it seems like way too much theorizing and explaining would be needed to reconcile that with how the faceless man interacts with them - I guess he could be the "Marla" of the situation? Or the entire thing could be in Arya's head? And **she** was actually the one who killed the people she named after she "met" the faceless man? Seems overly convoluted though.

Comment: There are *some* things that speak for this theory, namely that Arya and the kindly man (in the books) always refer to "Arya" in third person. And while Arya becomes "no one" in her day time, she is the "night wolf" in her dreams (warging into Nymeria). "Arya" also hid Needle to retrieve it later, which "Arya" in the tv-show did. However, in the books, the waif is a real person, and it seems a bit too vague for a tv-show to have such a plot.

Comment: IIRc, in the books Arya and the Kindly Man talk about the Waif, about her age and appearance. In this conversation Arya learns that the Waif is much older than she looks and this is due to her frequent contact with the death-water in the temple's pool, which the Waif prepares and refills on a daily basis. If this talk really happend (I do have to read the books again!), it would strongly oppose the theory that Arya and the Waif are the same person (in the books).

Comment: @user1129682 you're remembering mostly correctly. The Waif is stunted because she was poisoned not due to exposure to death water.

Comment: @user1129682 "The poisons" that the waif was exposed to was later revealed to be the ones that her father's new wife gave her, not the poisons in the temple. Her father asked for his wife to be given "the gift", for which he gave his daughter to the faceless men.

Comment: @TLP i totally can see my brain prefering arbitrary false memories over this true story. I can also see why the Waif insta-hates everyone who would run from their families

Comment: @user1129682 The waif never hated Arya.

Comment: I don't know if the Fight Club theory holds water in the TV series. There are several conversations between the Waif and Jaqen H'ghar where Arya isn't present, including one where Jaqen gives the Waif permission to hunt down Arya.

Comment: @RobertF Which makes perfect sense if Jaqen is aware of or even encouraging the situation. It's probably not true, but it makes for interesting watching.

Comment: @DCShannon - I see, you mean in the Jaqen-Waif scenes, the Waif was actually Arya in her alternate personality. Interesting but probably too confusing for most viewers. At any rate it was made clear in the last episode that the fight club theory isn't correct.

Comment: Would you mind to update this as Season 7's out now?